# Работа с сессиями на javaScript

Tags: javascript, сессия

Было задано

```
$_SESSION['device']='a';
```

Мне надо динамически при нажатии на ссылку, изменять значение. Есть ли для этого cредства в js?

Comment: используйте cookies, сессии это серверная сторона и с js ни как не связана. Сибо AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если поможет, то есть такое в jQuery -- [jQuery.session plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)
javascript не имеет доступа к сессиям, ЕМНИП конечно. может чтото и поменялось...

пример с плагином:

```
// To Store
$(function() {
    $.session.set("myVar", "value");
});

// To Read
$(function() {
    alert($.session.get("myVar"));
});
```

Comment: я как понимаю это client  side session, а ОП хочет значение в php сессии поменять.

Comment: спасибо. придумала решение без использования js

Comment: @eicto ну я как раз понял, что нажатие на ссылку происходит на стороне клиента, тем более раз уж был упомянут javascript ;) в противном случае вопрос бессмысленный и нерешаемый :)

Comment: @Thunder, ты прямой пример горе-программиста. JQuery написан на JS. Каким же образом расскажи мне, в нем нет того что есть в JQ? Логика отсутствует?

Comment: @ArthurAlekseenko ну так приведи пример, а не умничай в комментариях от 2013 года :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sessionStorage['detailPage'] = 'value';
alert(sessionStorage['detailPage']);
```

Comment: А вот это как раз хороший пример! +