# Как вывести $_SESSION[login] в JS

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть логин в `$_SESSION[login]`. И конструкция JS которая очищает див методом .text('') *(Когда я изменяю размер окна < 400px то очищаю див содержимое которого я задал `$_SESSION[login]` через PHP )*, так вот, как мне вернуть значение логина в див когда я обратно меняю размер окна > 400px?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с сессиями на javaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196396/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javascript)

Comment: @splash58 Вы хоть смотрели что там?

Comment: @splash58 ни разу не дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот так:

```
$login= "$_SESSION[login]"; 
$js_obj = json_encode($login); 
print "<script>var obj=$js_obj; alert(obj);</script>";
```